# Clearing a previous selection and selecting a row in datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My issue is entirely different one, initialy for example i will select the second row of the `datagridview`, after a button click i have to clear the second row selection and make the Selection on the First row, problem is the previous selection not at all clearing, and its not selecting the first row.
For clearing selection i used:

```
 dbgContCov.ClearSelection();

 this.dbgContCov.Rows.Clear();
 this.dbgContCov.Columns.Clear();
 dbgContCov.Refresh();
 dbgContCov.Parent.Refresh();
```

For  Selecting First Row:

```
 dbgContCov.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
 dbgContCov.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

i Dont want  to use `dbgContCov.CurrentCell = null;` because after setting this, even though i use  `dbgContCov.Rows[0].Selected = true;` the currentselected cell will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `CurrentCell` to `[0, 0]` to select the `first` row. No need to clear any selections or set null to `CurrentCell`.

```
dbgContCov.CurrentCell = dbgContCov[0, 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure MultiSelect property is set to false.

Comment: hi Sami,     Multiselect is set to false